# Twilio payment with call transfer functionality

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-click-to-call

**Any help will be much appreciated.**

I am stuck by a use case with Twilio. I don't even know if it is feasible or not. let me explain my use case if it is feasible please anyone point me in the right direction.

For explanation purposes let me use two entities: an agent and the customer. The agent will use a Twilio phone and the customer doesn't. so my proposed flow is as follows.

When the agent calls from a Twilio number to the customer ask him that his payment is pending. if the customer provides his consent then the agent will transfer that call to the payment number. (I have bought a separate number for payment purposes) now when the payment is completed I want to move that call to the same agent with which he was talking to. problem is I cannot move that call back to the same agent. As all agents are using the same number so if I call back to the old number there will be multiple agents and anyone can pick up the call again.

Another issue is that if a person talks first then the gathering event doesn't work.